# display picture overlapping css elemts

Tags: html, css, image

I would like to display image to the left (border same as left border of white section to the left of blue box). Now Image will be visible only when remove `background-image: linear-gradient(#a4c2e8,#e2eaf2);`

But I want to preserve the gradient effect. How to do that ?

```css
.quate_sidebar {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: -6px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-right: 126px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.quate_sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#a4c2e8, #e2eaf2);
  /* text styles */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4174c5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: initial;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -2px #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 5.5px 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
}

.quate_icon_1 {
  background: url(img/get_quate/get_quate_icon_1.png)no-repeat scroll 15px center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="quate_sidebar">
  <li class="quate_icon_1"><a href="#">Csab</a> </li>
  <li class="quate_icon_1"><a href="">Maryy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please refer the code here:
      https://jsfiddle.net/edp5o27u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following in `.quate_sidebar li`:

```
background-image: url('http:/placehold.it/30'), linear-gradient(#a4c2e8, #e2eaf2); background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
```

See also this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/edp5o27u/1/)

Comment: this is very nice solution..!!

Comment: yeah, I forgot that you could have more than one background on an element

Comment: But in this example how to display elements if different pictures are there for each section?

Comment: You would have to define different classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the icon background image to the `<a>` element, then you can keep the gradient background image on the `<li>` element.

```
.quate_sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#a4c2e8, #e2eaf2);
  /* text styles */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4174c5;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: initial;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px -2px #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 5.5px 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
}

a.quate_icon_1 {
  background: url(img/get_quate/get_quate_icon_1.png)no-repeat scroll 15px center;
}
```

Comment: i tried ..but this not solved problem

Comment: could you explain a bit more, as I may have misunderstood the nature of the problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/edp5o27u/1/ I need to display pictures on left side. But in this example how to display elements if different pictures are there for each section?